# CheckBox not getting checked in Knockoutjs

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I am using a checkbox with a function inside the `data-bind`, but I am unable to `check` the checkbox.

**view:**

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: function(){ f('hello parameter'); }">Click me
```

**View Model:**

```
var VM = function () {
    this.f = function (param) {
        alert(param); // here i am getting 'hello parameter'
        return true;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nishmoh/96358j1c/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default, the `click` binding prevents the default reaction to a click based on the assumption that your JavaScript click event handler will handle everything. You need to return "true" to get the default behavior anyway, which you are doing from your `f()` function but not the wrapper inside `data-bind`:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: function() { f('hello parameter'); }">
```

should be

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: function() { return f('hello parameter'); }">
```

Comment: yes it's working now . my bad i missed return . found other way `f.bind('hello parameter')` . Which is preferable ?

Comment: @supercool That would need to be `f.bind($root, 'hello parameter')` and is essentially the same. It all depends on whether you need `this` inside the function or not (if yes, using `bind()` may be necessary in some cases, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: FYI, you can also use `click: return f('...')`

Comment: @Niko, yep, it does work. Open the original fiddle, and replace your input with this one: `<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: return f('hello parameter'); ">` If it doesn't work for you let me know which browser you're using.

Comment: @jotaBe its working but how come ? any explanation is appreciated

Comment: @JotaBe Check the Javascript console, you will see that binding failed which is why the checkbox behaves as usual. You won't see the "hello parameter" output in the console.

Comment: Yep, Niko. You're fully right, and I'm plain wrong. So my comments above are completely wrong. The binding fails, with "return token unexpected".

Comment: How it works this way is ridiculous.

Answer (score 5):

Without context around the code it's not clear how you intend to use this control. With a checkbox you would normally use the **[checked binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)** that is bound to a boolean observable:

> The checked binding links a checkable form control — i.e., a checkbox () or a radio button () — with a property on your view model.

So another way of writing this using the **checked** binding would be:

**Sample Code:**

```js
var VM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.myCheck = ko.observable(false);

  self.myCheck.subscribe(function () {
    alert('checked value = ' + self.myCheck());
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myCheck" />
  Click me
</div>
```

With this example, there's an observable that tracks the value of the checkbox: `self.myCheck`. So when the checkbox is checked/unchecked, `self.myCheck()` will be set to true/false.

In order to provide some output or run some code when the value is changed, I've subscribed to the observable, which basically means that every time the value of the observable is changed, the alert will be fired (or whatever code you place in there).

### [Demo On JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96358j1c/13/)